# Vector into or out of the plane Symbol

Tags: plotting, vector

How do I add the symbol for vector into or out of the plane, at a given point, using graphics?

[image: Adding]

Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Notation_for_vectors_in_or_out_of_a_plane.svg

Comment: You could use `Inset`. I'll let you read the docs. If you get stuck you can flesh out the question - if you have code you're much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: `Translate[g, {a, b}]`, `g = {Circle[{0, 0}, 0.1], Point[{0, 0}]}` and so forth.

Comment: What about in 3D though?

Comment: Show a 3D figure of what you want.

Comment: usumdelphini, it would be better (for others to help answer your question) if you edit your question with the necessary information regarding wanting it in 3D, and then also do what MichaelE2 suggests. This type of clarification goes a long way towards making for a good QA that can be referenced by future users.